# Why won't Startup Disk writer write the latest Ubuntu ISO to DVD-ROM? (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: iso, brasero

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop ISO from the Ubuntu website, md5 checked it and its fine. However, when I put a Sony DVD-R AccuCORE 4.7GB disk in, Ubuntu recognizes it and allows me to write my own files (.doc, .exe, .txt, etc...) to it, but for some reason Brasero and Startup Disk Creator both don't recognize it and *refuse* to write the ISO to the disk???

Comment: damaged iso? check the md5

Comment: He said he did, @Web-E.

Comment: What does **Brasero** recognise the DVD as? Is these an error message?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: It does recognize it, but it says something along the lines of 'I don't recognize this disk, supply me with a CD-ROM...?' I'll get the exact wording soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after *much* deliberation, I have figured out that my disk drive doesn't write ISOs to these DVDs. Got a new pack, nope it's not the old DVDs, the news ones don't work either.

Windows XP Pro doesn't even recognize it at all, just sits there spinning and making weird noises.

So I took an ISO creator program to my newer system and voila it works. Very strange all in all, but I got what I wanted.